# Passing argument between functions/classes

Tags: javascript

In class `main.js` :

```
function readImage() {
    if (window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader) {
        var files = event.target.files; //FileList object

        for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            var file = files[i];
            if (!file.type.match('image')) continue;

        //* * * call function in storage class 
        uploadPhoto(file);
```

then i started a simple new js file to move uploading functionality into it.

in `storage.js`

```
    function uploadPhoto(file)
    {


           // create ref for fireStorage etc
            var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();

// ...more code using firebase with error every time i use it
```

Errors :

1. in class `storage` : `uploadPhoto is defined but never used`
2. error everytime I use `firebase` : `not defined`, where if I use `firebase` in `main.js` class **it does works-no errors** (so why not inside storage.js ?)

In my `html` both are defined :

```
 //firebase is defined here...
 <script src="javascripts/main.js"></script>
 <script src="javascripts/storage.js"></script>
```

Do I need to import something in `storage.js` to let it recognize the rest of the world ?

Comment: where you have imported uploadPhoto in main.js ? did you exported uploadPhoto from storage.js() ?

Comment: @CodeManiac I don't think stuff needs to be exported at all if it is in the global scope and used in HTML.

Comment: @CodeManiac these are being loaded with a script tag

Comment: @Curnelious Defined but never used seems like a Linter error, not a real JS error. That would be because the Linter cannot know that you are calling the function from another file. Can you confirm that?

Comment: I did not impot or export anything, simply a new file storage.js, and inside this functions. Do i need to change the order i include them in html ?

Comment: use import export things, its available in javascript

Comment: @diEcho It's not useful for normal JS in the browser. You'd need to transpile it for production.

Comment: @NikxDa: If you ignore IE, `import`/`export` is ready for production as-is, no transpiler needed.

Comment: I am not sure i understand all your complex words, I come from a background of software where you dont have to import anything, just call whatever you want. So if there is something I have to do to let the file storage.js know about the world, please let me know. right now it seems that it will not recognize anything outside of it- for example firebase, while main.js will. I simply started a new file from scratch.

Comment: Is it so complex in js to simply encapsulate your code? I just wanted to move functionality into a new file to make some order, so file1 call function in file2, that's it :)

Comment: @Amadan It only has around 80% browser compatibility, which can be ok, but is mostly unsuitable for large audiences. 
OP: Your code should be working fine, without importing/exporting. When are you calling the functions?

Comment: If you're not doing anything special (using modules, import, export, enclosing functions in other functions...), it should just work, as you said. Unless you're trying to call `uploadPhoto` immediately (before `storage.js` managed to load), for example. It is very difficult to say without knowing more. Also, as NikxDa said, "defined but never used" is not an error you should be able to get without extra tooling.

Comment: @Amadan thanks. "is not an error you should be able to get without extra tooling." what is tooling ? also you said  " Unless you're trying to call uploadPhoto immediately (before storage.js managed to load)" , what do you mean before its loaded? using Bootstrap, the user pick a file in his computer/phone, then inside main.js the callback readImage() is being called. there, I get reference to the file, and I would like to call uploadPhoto function that is inside storage.js, that's it, nothing special. Maybe should I include  <script src="javascripts/storage.js"></script> before main.js ?

Comment: Wait, inside storage.js I can not even call -  console.log('we are here!'); which also gives error : unexpected console statement. error on compile. not runtime.

Comment: "tooling" as in additional tools besides editor and browser, for example [linter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lint_(software)). As for the second point, browsers load JS files sequentially, only starting on the next one once the first one was loaded and executed (unless you specify otherwise), so if your `main.js` says `function blah() { ... uploadPhoto() ...}; blah()`, it will execute `blah`, which will try to execute `uploadPhoto`, but `storage.js` has not yet even started loading; that would lead to an error.

Comment: "Unexpected console statement" _definitely_ comes from ESLint, not from execution.

Comment: @Curnelious Are you using a transpiler or other tools before running your webpage?

Comment: Thanks everyone, it works great on browser, didn't bother to check because I had tones of errors on the editor. Guess I have to ignore those errors(?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent extended discussion in comments, I'm going to go through all that has been said and then explain to you what it means.

1. The first error you describe is `uploadPhoto is defined but never
   used`. This means that where you've defined `uploadPhoto`, it is
   never being called - which is perfectly fine, because you are
   calling it in `main.js`. You can just ignore this error.

> You should not be able to get such an error without additional
>   tooling, such as a Linter, that checks your code before it runs. Tools
>   like those would most probably give you these warnings in your editor,
>   and not inside a browser.

2. The second error you've mentioned is that you can use `firebase` in your `main.js` file, but not inside the other file. This should not be the case and is most probably based on the fact that `firebase` is *not yet available* when you are trying to use it in `storage.js`, i.e. it is still loading. To resolve this, please clarify when you are calling the functions inside `storage.js` and how your program flow executes.

Comment: Thanks. First, I use Brackets to write code, and errors are there already, not on runtime. Second, I can see that storage.js is also giving me error if I try to simply log : console.log gives an error on the editor, which seems like a more simple problem with this file (?)

Comment: You should not be focusing on Linter errors in Brackets, but rather on runtime errors. Can you clarify on that?

Comment: Also, how are you embedding `firebase`? Does the script tag have an async attribute by any chance?

Comment: Oh no, don't kill me but it works great on browser, i didn't even check because of all those errors (!) So should I completely ignore Linter errors ? why they are there if so ?

Comment: Linter errors are just hints, but Linters can often fail because they cannot grasp the whole extent of what you are doing, just like in your case. The Linter simply did not understand that you were using `uploadPhoto`, but you knew better. Same with Firebase - the Linter did not see that it was actually available.